# javascript parseFromString changing order of elements in xml doc

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

in my system, i had to move a big javascript ajax system to seam.  i got that to work correctly by adding

```
xml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(s, "text/xml");
```

now my problem is it has just come to my attention that the domparser is for some reason changing the order of the xml elements.  ive narrowed it down, it has to be this.  since these elements are sorted in a specific order when it leaves the server, the dom parser reorganizing is not a good thing.  anyone seen this? anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that is still is having this problem, i solved it by writing my own XML parser.  i stopped using DomParser all together and since this time, i have changed over to json which doesn't have the problem at all.

thanks

Comment: I have same problem. can you provide solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

I've run across this issue in IE 9 RC 1 Standards mode trying to get around another issue (the XMLHttpRequest object returning an MSXML ActiveX object even when in Standards mode. Feature detection sees the DOMParser and the two documents are not compatible so I figured using the DOMParser would do the trick)

Sample code that reproduces the issue in IE 9 RC 1:

```
var sXML = "<TEST ID=\"124\" TITLE=\"TitleValue\" DATE=\"2011-02-24T00:00:00\" STATUS=\"Processing\" EMPNAME=\"Smith, Sam\" STATUSCODE=\"P\" ROWNUM=\"1\" />";

var dpParser = new DOMParser();
var xdDoc = dpParser.parseFromString(sXML, "text/xml");

var xsSerialize = new XMLSerializer();
var sNewXML = xsSerialize.serializeToString(xdDoc);

alert("Original XML:\n" + sXML + "\n\nNew XML:\n" + sNewXML);
```

The alert's output...

Original XML:

```
<TEST ID="124" TITLE="TitleValue" DATE="2011-02-24T00:00:00" STATUS="Processing" EMPNAME="Smith, Sam" STATUSCODE="P" ROWNUM="1" />
```

New XML:

```
<TEST ROWNUM="1" STATUSCODE="P" EMPNAME="Smith, Sam" STATUS="Processing" DATE="2011-02-24T00:00:00" TITLE="TitleValue" ID="124" />
```

Update:
 I had filed a bug report with Microsoft for IE 9 regarding this issue and they have resolved it as 'by design'.

If you expect your XML attributes in a certain order when using the DOMParser.parseFromString function in IE 9, you will want to grab the attributes explicitly rather than simply iterating over them.

The following was the bug report:
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/645091/domparser-parsefromstring-in-ie-9-rc-1-rearranges-the-attributes-of-the-xml-node-passed-in

Comment: Is it the DOMParser that is reordering your xml, or the XmlSerializer?

Comment: The link works but you need to sign up with Microsoft Connect and they get you to fill in a short survey before you can see any of the bugs...It's the DOMParser that is reordering the attributes (I stepped through in debug mode to be sure - iterating over the attribute collection using the index will also show this)

Comment: Yeah, I've signed in, still doesn't work :) Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/iulvf.png

Maybe its tied to your login?

Comment: I didn't realize there were so many steps needed...I logged in with my dad's account and i get the error you described. I had to actually join the Internet Explorer Feedback Program (home page, click on 'Browse' for the Products currently accepting bugs) and filled out the survey before I could see the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I would be extremely surprised if this is the case. Node order is defined as being significant in XML and I can't believe any browser's implementation of `DomParser` would fail to respect it. I suggest you look again at your code.

Comment: i already have, its very strange.  when its in ajax mode and jquery returns a xmlresponse object, its perfect.  but when in seam mode i have to parse it into a dom document and when i get the document out its in a different order.  and in both cases the server sends the exact same xml as a response.  ive verified it two different ways.

Comment: Is there a test page you can post?